# HashSet internal storing same hash bucket

Tags: java, hashset

How are the following Person objects being stored inside the same hash bucket ? As a linked list ? Also, according to java 8, if a certain treshhold is reached, the linked list is transformed into an tree ? Is this also correct ?

```
class TestHashSet
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Person p1 = new Person("Mike");
        Person p2 = new Person("Mike");
        Set persons = new HashSet();
        persons.add(p1);
        persons.add(p2);

        Iterator iterator = persons.iterator(); 
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println("Value: "+((Person)iterator.next()).getName() + " ");  
        }

    }
}

class Person {
    String name;

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return name.hashCode();
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
                        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because your `equals` always retrun `false`.

Comment: yes, i know that...my question was about the storing inside the same hash bucket. Is that a linked list ?

Comment: How do you know ? AFAIK there is no way to get the buckets list from those implementation...

Comment: they should be inside the same bucket because they have the same hashcode

Comment: So what your **wrong** code for? A `HashSet` is just a `HashMap`. The two `Person` of course in same bucket because they have same hash code. And the bucket is a linked list, you can check `HashMap#Node`.

Comment: @DeanXu Since Java 8 a mechanism has been implemented so that from a certain threshold on the colliding entries are stored in form of a balanced tree to reduce the time of searching for the right entry to **O(log n)**

Comment: @L.Spillner I know it, so what the question is?

Comment: just wanted a confirmation about these things..Dean Xu, you can add a response not just a comment, so i can accept it

Comment: @DeanXu **As a linked list ? Also, according to java 8, if a certain treshhold is reached, the linked list is transformed into an tree ? Is this also correct ?** - Guess the answer is simply 'yes' that statement is correct and colliding entries are first stored as a linked list and later on after a certain threshold as a tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes. Colliding entries are first stored as a linked list and later on
>   after a certain threshold as a tree

Answer (score 0):

For your **1st question**, the 2 objects will be stored as 2 different entries in the hash set. The reason being the false returned from equals method.

The 2 objects are compared. First of all, hash code is checked. Since same hash code is found, equals method is checked, which returns false, and hence the object is stored again.

The important thing to note here is that since the hash codes are same, they get into the same bucket, but as 2 different entries (as a scenario of collision).

For the **2nd question**, as of java 8, binary tree is used instead of linked list for the purpose **after a certain threshold** is reached. For reference, check https://www.nagarro.com/de/blog/post/24/performance-improvement-for-hashmap-in-java-8